# How can I use innerHTML to put text over an image?

Tags: image, html, innerhtml

I am implementing an input text with an `onkeyup` that calls a JavaScript function. I have to put that text over an image, so I was thinking to use innerHtml inside a div that is on the image.

The div:

```
<div id="image3" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:519px; top:423px; width:474px; height:205px; z-index:4">
  <div id="uno" style="z-index:20">
      <img src="images/base-personalizzazione.png" alt="" title="" border=0 width=474 height=205>
    </div>
</div>
```

The input:

```
<input name="formtext1" id="ft1" style="position:absolute;width:571px;left:319px;top:194px;z-index:6" onkeyup="go(this.value)">
```

The JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function go(asd){
      document.getElementById('uno').innerHTML=asd;
   }
</script>
```

When I write inside input text image will disappear and text appear with background white. Can you help my work out why this happens and what I can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the innerHTML removes what used to be in the div.
One way to fix this would be to change the html to

```
<div id="image3" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:519px; top:423px; width:474px; height:205px; z-index:4">
  <div id="uno" style="z-index:20">
    <div id="input"></div>
    <img src="images/base-personalizzazione.png" alt="" title="" border=0 width=474 height=205>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then use innerhtml on the input div instead.

Comment: oh, you want to have the text above the image. You might want to use background-image on a div

Comment: <div id="image3" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:519px; top:423px; width:474px; height:205px; z-index:4;"><div id="input" style="background-image: url(images/base-personalizzazione.png);width:474px; height:205px;z-index:5"></div></div> in this way image is not visible!!